# Is it safe to use a 100 watt LED bulb in a 3-way lamp that specifies using incandescent bulbs only?

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture

I purchased a 100 watt LED and a 3 way lamp, but now that it is all assembled I have just read in the instructions:

> Lamp is rated for max 150 watt incandescent, Type A E-26, 3-way bulb. DO NOT USE HALOGEN BULB WITH THIS LAMP. Halogen bulbs operate at a higher temperature and pose a fire hazard

They don't mention LED. Is it safe for me to use the LED bulb? I just don't want to start a fire and I didn't see anything posted about safety warnings in the instructions.

Comment: Is the LED bulb an actual 3-way bulb equivalent?

Comment: @MichaelKaras, With an LED, 3 way becomes mute.  The switch becomes on/off and not off/low/med/high.  As for LED, I'm assuming it's a 100 watt equivalent which would be safe to use.  LED's of equivalent wattage as incandescent run much cooler.

Comment: @diceless: I don't know what the original poster purchased but there are actually 3-way LED bulbs.

Comment: @HenryJackson, I would love to find some.  All my table lamps are 3 way and the 3 way CF's are too big to fit.  Haven't seen any 3 way LED's in stores in my area so just using standard LED's in them.

Comment: @diceless: The Home Depot near me has a few 3-way LED models in stock and more online. Also I see Amazon.com has a few as well. They're more expensive than "regular" bulbs but the prices seem to be coming down.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upgrading to LED Bulbs](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/49078/upgrading-to-led-bulbs)

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming this is a 100 watt **equivalent** bulb, that is actually only running 18-20 watts.  Using a 100 watt equivalent will be safe as they run much cooler than even an incandescent.

Answer (score 1):

LED's of any consumer wattage run cool enough to use in any incandescent-rated socket.  The warning is specific to halogen incandescent bulbs, which run hotter than standard incandescents.

Go for it.

Answer (score -1):

In general yes. Use an LED bulb that is marked 'dimmable', and do not use it in an enclosed glass fixture -- many of the bulbs are made of plastic and can melt.

Also, look for a bulb that has more even light distribution; older bulbs often had the LED elements on a rectangular bar that created 'stripes' of higher and lower intensity light, all of which looks terrible in a lamp.

Comment: Getting a dimmable will have no effect.  3-way is not the same as dimmable (the former uses two filaments at mains voltage, the latter uses reduced voltages)